# Nautilus does not remember sort order of home directory

Tags: nautilus, file-sorting

On my machine (Ubuntu 20.04), default sort order of Nautilus is set to "name".

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order
'name'
```

Yet, when opening Nautilus, my home folder is always sorted by "last modified".

Moreover, Nautilus does not remember folder-specific changes regarding file ordering. When manually selecting an order, moving to another folder, and coming back, selected ordering has not been preserved. Hence, I cannot change the default ordering of my home folder.

Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: alternative like Krusader , menu, window, save position (for all tabs)

Comment: GNOME nautilus 3.36.3 does remember sort order of each folder.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this will help you, but at least it worked for me, so let's try it.

**Using terminal**
First, you can continue using `gsettings` CLI tools and use the `set` command to set the configuration you want. Example:

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.list-view default-visible-columns "['name', 'size', 'date_created', 'date_modified', 'detailed_type']"
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order 'type'
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-hidden-files 'true'
```

These are the command that I use in my setup Ubuntu base Linux script
**NOTE**: I no longer use Ubuntu, but I use Pop_OS! which is Ubuntu based so this might work.

**Using GUI application**
I believe this app is also available for Ubuntu. Its call **dconf editor** and to install you can use the terminal (actually it is the only way that I know lol).

```bash
sudo apt update;
sudo apt install dconf-editor -y
```

The first line is to update your local repo and the second is to install.
**NOTE**:

1. `apt` is what my system uses as a package manage
2. In the second line the `-y` flag is to say yes to any promo that apt request from you
   After that, you open the app and use it. It is pretty straightforward.

I hope that you still need this help and this help whomever look at this.